# akka streams - Triggering the flow of elements while using conflate

Tags: akka-stream

I was trying to create a service over a web socket that would accept JSON and then when triggered, emit the last received value.  My sample code is:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Broadcast, Flow, GraphDSL, ZipWith}
import akka.stream._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.mvc.WebSocket
import play.core.server.{AkkaHttpServer, Server, ServerConfig}
import play.api.routing.sird._
import scala.io.StdIn

object Trigger extends App {

    import GraphDSL.Implicits._
    implicit val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("trigger")
    implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system)

    val triggerFilter = Flow[JsValue].filter(json => (json \ "trigger").isDefined)
    val dataFilter = Flow[JsValue].filter(json => (json \ "trigger").isEmpty)

    val triggerBatching = Flow[JsValue].conflate((acc, elem) => elem)
    val dataBatching = Flow[JsValue].conflate((acc, elem) => elem)

    val partial = GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
        val B = builder.add(Broadcast[JsValue](outputPorts = 2))
        val zip = builder.add(ZipWith((msg: JsValue, trigger: JsValue) => msg))

        B ~> dataFilter.async    ~> dataBatching.async    ~> zip.in0
        B ~> triggerFilter.async ~> triggerBatching.async ~> zip.in1

        FlowShape(B.in, zip.out)
    }.named("partial")

    val flow = Flow.fromGraph(partial)

    val BufferSize: Int = 100
    val Port: Int = 9001

    val server: Server = AkkaHttpServer.fromRouterWithComponents(ServerConfig(
        port = Some(Port),
        address = "127.0.0.1"
    )) { components => {
        case GET(p"/ws") => WebSocket.accept[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
            flow.buffer(size = BufferSize, overflowStrategy = OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
        }
    }}

    if (StdIn.readLine(s"${java.time.Instant.now()} - Press RETURN to stop...\n") != null) {
        server.stop()
    }
}
```

The behavior I was trying to achieve would be:

1. send {"A": 1}, receive nothing
2. send {"A": 2}, receive nothing
3. send {"A": 3}, receive nothing
4. send {"trigger": true}, receive {"A": 3}
5. send {"trigger": true}, receive nothing

But what I'm seeing is:

1. send {"A": 1}, receive nothing
2. send {"A": 2}, receive nothing
3. send {"A": 3}, receive nothing
4. send {"trigger": true}, receive {"A": 1}
5. send {"trigger": true}, receive {"A": 2}
6. send {"trigger": true}, receive {"A": 3}
7. send {"trigger": true}, receive nothing

What am I misunderstanding about either zip or conflate or other that's preventing the inbound JSON from being consolidated prior to receiving the trigger and responding with the latest message?

Comment: I added `.async.addAttributes(Attributes.inputBuffer(initial = 1, max = 1))` to the ZipWith and two conflate flows, and it's a bit better.  If I send 6 messages before the trigger, I get the first message returned, which I think makes sense since that would arrive at the zip fan in and wait for the trigger.  If I send a second trigger, I get the second message, but then on the third trigger, I receive the 6th element, which is closer to the behavior I was trying to create.  `B.out(0) ~> dataFilter    ~> dataBatching    ~> zip.in0`
`B.out(1) ~> triggerFilter ~> triggerBatching ~> zip.in1`

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly the, the first message sits in the zip inlet0 waiting for the trigger.  The second element then sits in the ZipWith's buffer.  Every subsequent message is then run through the conflate until the trigger is received, at which point the first message is emitted from ZipWith, the second element moves from the buffer to the zip inlet0, and the value from the conflate (the 6th message in this case) moves to ZipWith's buffer.  Is that an accurate description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`conflate`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/conflate.html) applies when the downstream is slower than the upstream. In your case, the upstream (i.e., the data that the standard input is reading) is slower than the downstream, so no conflation occurs.

When you send the data--`{"A":1}`, `{"A":2}`, and `{"A":3}`--you initially receive nothing because there are no corresponding elements with which to zip them. These data elements are [buffered internally](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-rate.html#introduction) (the default buffer size is 16) until you send the trigger messages, which serve as the second element in the zipped-up pairs that are emitted downstream.

To see the desired behavior with `conflate`, make the downstream slower than the upstream. This is kind of tricky in your case because you're manually entering the stream elements. One idea is to add a [`throttle`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/throttle.html#throttle) to your flows:

```
val triggerBatching =
  Flow[JsValue]
    .conflate((acc, elem) => elem)
    .throttle(1, 10 seconds)

val dataBatching =
  Flow[JsValue]
    .conflate((acc, elem) => elem)
    .throttle(1, 10 seconds)
```

Then make sure you're entering the input messages fast enough.

Comment: Thanks.  That was the piece that I was initially missing - the elements getting queued up in the ZipWith's buffer that had the default size of 16, which was allowing them to pass straight through conflate w/out any sort of aggregation.